# Is there a way to use R to place a list of students in different grades into different class options?

Tags: r

So kind of a weird question, but does anyone have ideas on how I could take a list of, say, 250 students who have all chosen from a list of 7 class options and ranked their top 4 classes, and then use R to place students in these classes? The classes have a size limit, and there are some students that can't be with other students, etc.

Again a weird question, but does anyone think its feasible to place students in classes according to their top 4 classes, grade level, as well as by who can't be with who, etc.

Comment: this is a bit vague tbh, and you may get downvotded for this question. what are the criteria for kids not being with other kids? what does the data look like? what are the rules for which preference the kids get?

Comment: To yield a useful answer you need to provide more information, preferably with a reproducible example, and not a passing question. It sounds like you do not have a simple assignment problem but, rather one with rules/conditions and limited outcomes. Sounds much more like an optimization problem then query based. You can use `dput` for an object, representing your data, that you can copy-and-paste in as code to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry! This is my first time posting on stackoverflow and I'm new to R. I'll post again when I have the data ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an assignment problem that can be formulated and solved as an integer programming problem.  For i students and j classes the decision variables are assigning the ith student to the jth class for all students and classes.  The objective function is to maximize the total satisfaction of all of the students.  The coefficients of the objective function are the preferences for each student/class pairing.

The constraints as you described would also be incorporated into the formulation.

This model can be solved in R using the roi and ompr mathematical programming packages:

http://roi.r-forge.r-project.org/

https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/

ompr is a programming interface that calls roi optimization functions.

BTW, since you have a preference function of only 4 discrete values there could be many degenerate solutions.  I.e. different i,j allocations with the same objective function value.